# Change default recipients for Jenkins email-ext plugin using Groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins, email-ext

I would like to be able to modify the list of default recipients of my Jenkins build emails based on a support rota. Currently I'm struggling to find out how to do this.

So far I have tried this:

```
import jenkins.model.*;
import org.kohsuke.stapler.*;

def plugin = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getDescriptorByType(hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisherDescriptor.class);

println plugin.getClass();

plugin.configure(new StaplerRequest());
```

I can see that I'm successfully getting the `Descriptor` for the plugin that I wish to configure but not really sure where to go from here.

I now understand that `StaplerRequest` is an interface. Is there an implementation that I can instantiate and set the required parameter?

From looking at the *email_ext* [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/) I can see that the parameter I might want to set is `ext_mailer_default_recipients`. Additionally I can see in the configuration file  *hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.xml* the XML element I want to update is called `recipientList`.

Can anyone suggest how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

To configure Extended Email Publisher with plain Groovy, you can do use the following code:

```
extendedMailer = j.getDescriptorByType(hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisherDescriptor.class)
extendedMailer.setDefaultSuffix("@server.local")
extendedMailer.setDefaultContentType("text/html")
extendedMailer.setSmtpServer("my-smtp.server.local")
extendedMailer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [job-dsl-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) to change the jobs. This would be a separate job (for your case) which could be timed to go off as the rota changed

as mentioned in the [wiki](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block#configure-email-notification)

```
def emailTrigger = {
    trigger {
        email {
            recipientList '$PROJECT_DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS'
            subject '$PROJECT_DEFAULT_SUBJECT'
            body '$PROJECT_DEFAULT_CONTENT'
            sendToDevelopers true
            sendToRequester false
            includeCulprits false
            sendToRecipientList true
        }
    }
}

job {
    configure { project ->
        project / publisher << 'hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher' {
              recipientList 'Engineering@company.com'
              configuredTriggers {
                  'hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.trigger.FailureTrigger' emailTrigger
                  'hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.trigger.FixedTrigger' emailTrigger
              }
              contentType 'default'
              defaultSubject '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT'
              defaultContent '$DEFAULT_CONTENT'
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT

I think this can be achieved moe easily using the later example

```
job {
    publishers {
        extendedEmail('Engineering@company.com') {
            trigger(triggerName: 'Failure', recipientList: '$PROJECT_DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS')
            trigger(triggerName: 'Fixed', recipientList: '$PROJECT_DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS')
        }
    }
}
```

This is a part example and you would need to look at templates for jobs before making wholesale changes

Answer (score 0):

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisherDescriptor
Jenkins jenkins
def plugin = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getDescriptorByType(hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisherDescriptor.class);
print plugin
plugin.setSmtpServer("your server")
plugin.setDefaultSuffix("your suffix")
plugin.save()
```

This works fine for me.